# Data Import With Login

Tags: vba, excel, cookies

I'm looking to create a macro for my office. This macro imports data from websites using the  `With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=` code.

The issue is that anyone who uses this macro will need to sign into the website I am trying to reach. Since I am using the Query command, the query requires the login, and not the IE object.

Right now, I have people go to the data ribbon and clicking "from web" to load the website up and sign in that way, then exiting it and running the macro. This allows the Query to reach the login cookies and the code runs fine. I need a way to streamline this so it's not so complicated.

Right now, I have a userbox that loads when the worksheet is opened that allows users to enter in their user login and password. Then this userbox saves that information in a different sheet.

I'm looking for a way to use the information they entered to "login" to the query import because having users go to the data ribbon is just a pain in the butt for everybody; and just makes my code look sloppy. Is there a way to login to a query website automatically?

*Even if I automate the login from an IE Application, the query still asks for a login. This makes me think that the cookies stored from IE and the query language are separate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the site authentication token(cookie) and the query language credentials (DB login) are two separate things. The site level credentials are authentication and the DB level credentials are authorization.

A typical authentication token is stored in the browser for a given session and is passed back to the site via the header of the HTTP request.  Your worksheet macro is making the request for information using the current browser context, but if you don't have a browser open already it will create a temporary instance of the IE object in order to send the data.

I found a forum where someone was trying to do this exact same thing, and it looks like they were able to do so.

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/421541-web-query-password-protected-web-sites-3.html

Here is the relevant code edited for this question:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.somesecuresite.com/login.html"
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    .document.all.Item("username").Value = "ldfsdfh"
    .document.all.Item("password").Value = "lkjgshdgsh"
    .document.forms(0).submit
End With

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;{your connection string}", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "WebData"
    .FieldNames = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: Thanks! I can give this a try later; instead of opening IE minimized, would it work if I just did the "objIE.Visible = False" command? Also, would this need to run every single time I run the query or only once when I open the excel document? If I'm running looping a query for 1000 items, I'd hate to have to wait for it to log in every single time.

Additionally, you emphasized the word "POST". Is this a VBA command that I am unaware of?

Comment: Last question: when I use the command to call the query using "ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=", will I need to somehow reference the open minimized IE document? Or will the URL work fine?

Comment: Update: I automated the opening of IE (not hidden), then ran the query from that URL once logged in and the query is still telling me to log in.

Comment: Sounds like the IE and the worksheet are two different sessions.  What version of the worksheet application are you using?  Knowing this, I may be able to help you launch an instance of the browser from within the program so that it is the same session.

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 and IE 9 (soon to be upgraded to IE 11 next week I believe). If you could figure this out, that would be amazing! I have tried other methods but nothing has worked thus far. This issue is putting a huge damper on my code which is difficult for someone like myself who is trying to learn

Comment: Any luck on this? I can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment but I don't have enough reps to comment XD Your problem is beyond me but having recently used API to automate password entry in Excel, perhaps it's a direction you can look into? Basically, you can grab the handle of a particular window then interact with it such as filling fields/password or pressing buttons.
A good example via http://www.siddharthrout.com/2013/04/24/unprotecting-vba-project-password-using-a-password-that-you-know/#!prettyPhoto